# How to send logs to mocked CloudWatch?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, python-unittest, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I would like to test my query function that is returning logs with specific id.
It looks like this:

```
result = cw_query(log_id, log_groups)
```

I want to write an unittest that tests this function (it should return my logs), so i have something like this:

```
class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    @mock_cloudwatch
    def test_cw_query(self):
        result = cw_query("t3st", ["watchtower"])
        logger.info(result)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

The problem is that I don't know how I should send some logs to the mocked cloudwatch in the unittest before I use the query function.
I tried using Watchtower but that didn't work.
Please help me.

EDIT: cw_query looks like this:

```
def cw_query(cid: str, log_group_names: List[str]) -> dict:
query_string = f"fields @timestamp, @message" \
               f" | filter @message like /{cid}/" \
               f" | sort @timestamp desc" \
               f" | limit 100"

start_query_response = client.start_query(
    logGroupNames=log_group_names,
    startTime=int((datetime.today() - timedelta(days=7)).timestamp()),
    endTime=int(datetime.now().timestamp()),
    queryString=query_string
)

query_id = start_query_response["queryId"]

response = None

while response is None or response['status'] == 'Running':
    logger.info('Waiting for query to complete ...')
    time.sleep(1)
    response = client.get_query_results(
        queryId=query_id
    )

logger.info(response)
return response
```

Comment: Which is the expected functionality you want to assert in this test? Can you provide the code of `cw_query`? Thanks

Comment: @EricLozano I would like to test that the function returns the logs with the specific id, so I'll assert if the result list is not empty. Also i edited my post with the code. Thanks!